# Dimension of Kahler differentials of Laurent series over perfect field.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be perfect field, char $k=p>0$. How it can be shown that $\dim_{k((t))}\Omega^1(k((t)))=1$?

Comment: This depends on how you define the Kähler differentials of Laurent series. With the correct definition, they are generated by dt, hence the dimension is $1$.

Comment: @Cantlog I define Kahler defferentials of an algebra $R/k$ as a universal module $D$ with a $k$-linear map $d: R \to D$ s.t. $d(xy)=xd(y)+yd(x)$. It is not obviously that it is generated by $dt$, because it is not true if char $k$=0.

Comment: If you use this purely algebraic definition, then $\Omega$ has infinite dimension over $k((t))$.

Comment: This is discussed in [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21189/the-structure-of-the-module-of-kahler-differentials-of-rx-over-r) MathOverflow thread. In particular, see the comment by Harri Gindi, where he sketches a proof.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer: you are right in positive characteristics.